# Помогите разобраться с скриптом select option input value id

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите разобраться с скриптом.
есть такой скрипт

```html
<input class="catSelector9" checked="checked" type="hidden" value="2" name="ocat" id="cus2">

 <select class="car_Marka" id="car_Marka" onchange="run()">  
     <option id="cus2" value="2">AC</option>
     <option id="cus3" value="3">ACURA</option>
     <option id="cus5" value="5">ADLER</option>
     <option id="cus4" value="4">AUDI</option>
</select>

<script> 
 function run(){
       document.getElementById ("cus2").value = document.getElementById("car_Marka").value;
  
    }
</script>
```

При выборе `option` меняется только `input value`. Но мне надо, чтобы при выборе `option`, менялся `input value` и `input id`.

Здесь я понял, что при первой смене `input id` скрипт не работает, 
а можно ли это выполнение сделать с помощью `input class` и `select class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы делать выборку с помощью `class` можно использовать jQuery

```js
$(".car_Marka").on("change", function() {
    var selected_option = $(".car_Marka option:selected");
    $(".catSelector9")
      .attr("id",    selected_option.attr("id"))
      .attr("value", selected_option.attr("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="catSelector9" checked="checked" type="hidden" value="2" name="ocat" id="cus2">

 <select class="car_Marka" id="car_Marka">  
     <option id="cus2" value="2">AC</option>
     <option id="cus3" value="3">ACURA</option>
     <option id="cus5" value="5">ADLER</option>
     <option id="cus4" value="4">AUDI</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: но почему то на странице не работает. на компьютере вставлю tes.html вес код с этого страницы http://avtousta.ucoz.com/board/0-0-0-0-1 и ваш код который переделали. сохраняю открываю в браузере хром работает отлично. Тот же код копирую вставлю в страницу не как не работает.

Comment: Спасибо вам ваш скрипт по функции класс работает отлично, но только в обычном браузере при тесте, а при загрузке на страницу не работает. загляните пожалуйста вот на это скрипт `<div id="ad-car-detail-content">
 </div>


     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/board/add-cars-board.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div id="ad-car-detail-content">
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://avtousta.ucoz.com/js/board/add-cars-board.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>$("select.car_Marka").on("change", function() {var selected_option = $("select.car_Marka option:selected");$("input.catSelector9").attr("id", selected_option.attr("id")).attr("value", selected_option.attr("value"));});</script>
```

DmitryScaletta: Помог спасибо!
но код на странице не работает! а на компьютере при тесте работает отлично